# Compare times with pandas and change font according to result

Tags: python, python-3.x, cell, xlsxwriter

I need to change the color of a cell if its value is lower than 08:00:00, it worked on integer but not on strings

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()


# Add a format. Light red fill with dark red text.
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                               'font_color': '#9C0006'})

# Add a format. Green fill with dark green text.
format2 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#C6EFCE',
                               'font_color': '#006100'})


import pandas as pd

data= pd.DataFrame({'Time':['07:02:07', '15:16:55', '15:17:20', '15:28:58','15:32:28','15:38:54'],
 'Payload':['[0]->[1]', '[1]->[0]','[0]->[1]','[0]->[1]','[1]->[0]','[0]->[1]']})

caption = ('Cells with values >= 08:00:00 are in light red. '
           'Values < 50 are in light green.')

# Write the data.
worksheet1.write('A1', caption)

for row, row_data in enumerate(data):
    worksheet1.write_row(row + 2, 1, row_data)

if len (data) >0:    
    for i in range (len(data)):

        worksheet1.write('D'+str(i+5),(data['Time'].iloc[i]))
        worksheet1.write('E'+str(i+5),(data['Payload'].iloc[i]))




# Write a conditional format over a range.
worksheet1.conditional_format('D5:D12', {'type': 'cell',
                                         'criteria': '>=',
                                         'value': '08:00:00',
                                         'format': format1})

workbook.close()
```

the code above is just an example, in my original code the time is the result of previous calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issue in the code but the main one is that the values like '07:02:07' are strings and not dates/times.

In order for them to work as times in Excel they need to be converted to datetime objects. After that the program should work. Here is an example with some fixes:

```py
import xlsxwriter
import datetime

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test4.xlsx')
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()


# Add a format. Light red fill with dark red text.
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                               'font_color': '#9C0006'})

# Add a format. Green fill with dark green text.
format2 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#C6EFCE',
                               'font_color': '#006100'})


import pandas as pd

data= pd.DataFrame({'Time': [datetime.time(7, 2, 7), datetime.time(15 ,16, 55), 
                             datetime.time(15 ,17, 20), datetime.time(15 ,28, 58), 
                             datetime.time(15 ,32, 28), datetime.time(15 ,38, 54)],
                    'Payload': ['[0]->[1]', '[1]->[0]','[0]->[1]',
                                '[0]->[1]','[1]->[0]','[0]->[1]']})

caption = ('Cells with values >= 08:00:00 are in light red. '
           'Values < 50 are in light green.')

# Write the data.
worksheet1.write('A1', caption)

for row, row_data in enumerate(data):
    worksheet1.write(row + 2, 1, row_data)

time_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'hh:mm::ss'})

if len (data) >0:    
    for i in range (len(data)):

        worksheet1.write('D'+str(i+5),(data['Time'].iloc[i]), time_format)
        worksheet1.write('E'+str(i+5),(data['Payload'].iloc[i]))




# Write a conditional format over a range.
worksheet1.conditional_format('D5:D12', {'type': 'date',
                                         'criteria': '>=',
                                         'value':  datetime.time(8, 0, 0),
                                         'format': format1})

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]